# Have .bat display info during execution (of WinSCP)

Tags: windows, bash, batch-file, ftp, winscp

Before I start I want to say thank you in advance for any help provided. This is my first post and I have tried to follow the rules. I checked but couldn't find this answered anywhere.

I have a batch file that I have set to run at a scheduled time daily. The file uses WinSCP to grab the contents of a folder on a server and copies them to a local directory. The size of the transfer is about 1.2GB - 1.5GB and takes about 20 seconds. I would like to display some information while the transfer happens. I'm looking for a way to display the bytes per second going over my network interface (*or similar*) in the same cmd window as the transfer.

I figured out how to get the info I want to display by doing:

```
typeperf "\Network Interface(Realtek PCIe GbE Family Controller)\Bytes Received/sec"
```

I'm just wondering if there is a way to display the information that is returned from the typeperf command while my file transfer completes. Then, at the end of the transfer have the window close. Sort of like some text that says "Please Wait" while the program runs except it would show bytes/sec over the interface.

Here is my script i use for the WinSCP FTP transfer with the ip and username removed:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.exe" /ini=nul /command "open ftp://UserNamer:StrongPassword1@###.###.###.###/" "cd /ShooterGame/Saved" "lcd ""D:\ARK Server Backup""" "get SavedArk57057" "exit"
```

Looking forward to any help that can be provided, assuming what I was is actually possible.

Comment: Try this: `start "" /B "The WinSCP.exe command" and its parameters` followed by `typeperf "\Network Interface(Realtek PCIe GbE Family Controller)\Bytes Received/sec" -sc 20`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WinSCP itself shows a transfer progress. Except that you run WinSCP in a hidden mode.

[Replace `winscp.exe` with `winscp.com`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/executables) to display a transfer progress in a console window.

[image]

---

If you want to display a progress in your own custom format, use [WinSCP .NET assembly](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library) [for example [from a PowerShell script](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_powershell)] instead of WinSCP scripting. And handle [`Session.FileTransferProgress` event](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_filetransferprogress).

There's a guide for [converting WinSCP script to PowerShell script with use of WinSCP .NET assembly](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_from_script).